# How to verify if there is a circle in a tree?

Tags: data-structures, directed-graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Here is a tree:

> 1. There will be one root.
> 2. Each tree node has zero or more children.
> 3. It is allowed that two nodes points to the same child. Say, both node A
>    and node B has child C.

However, it is prohibited that,

> Node A is an offspring of Node B, and
> Node B is an offspring of Node A.

One prohibited case is

> Node A has a child Node C and Node D,
>
> Both Node C and D has a child node E,
>
> Node E has a child of A.

The question is, how to determine this circle in a fastest manner?

**UPDATE**: I realize this is to find any cycle in a directed graph. Just now I managed to think out a solution similar to Tarjan's algorithm.

Thanks for comments.

Comment: This is called a "cycle" (not circle) in graph theory. You are trying to verify that a give graph is a "directed acyclic graph" or DAG for short. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Comment: Also, this question has already been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph

Comment: The data structure you have is a directed graph, not a tree. A tree node can't have multiple parents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) through the tree. If at any point you find a node that is already in your backtracking stack, there is a circle.

Comment: It will fail for this case: A->B, B->C, A->C

Comment: sorry, that should have read "stack" instead of "parent. Fixed it.

Comment: Since there'll be nodes that can be reached by multiple paths without creating a cycle (think a->(b,c)->d) a simple BFS implementation would detect false positives.

Answer (score 0):

circles can be found using 2 pointers and advancing them at different intervals.  Eventually the pointers will match, indicating a loop, or the "faster" one will reach then end.  The question is usually asked of linked lists though, not trees.

Comment: I'm not sure this would be the *fastest manner* of doing it, but rather the *lowest memory overhead manner*. Also, it sounds complicated to do for a tree.

Comment: The problem will be easy for a linked list. But consider this problem - the tree wil have multiple ends. Instead a linked list has only one end.

Comment: yeah ... that's why I said the question is usually asked of lists, not trees.  you'd have to run this for each node of the tree using a queue to remember the "next" nodes of each node as new starting points.  It would be ugly.