# Why is depth first search prefered over breadth first search to check for cycles in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

Why is depth first search preferred over breadth first search to check for cycles in a graph?

Comment: There is a good answer for this question on Stackoverflow [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869647/why-dfs-and-not-bfs-for-finding-cycle-in-graphs