# Why DFS and not BFS for finding cycle in graph

Tags: charts, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Give the reasons for the above my query

I find the above questions of the traverse of graph. Bfs and DFS both are the traverse to detect the cycle in a graph but most is the dfs why this is the best to solve the graph of a cycle

Answer (score 0):

1.When I code graph traversals, the dfs stack is easier to implement than a queue.

2.Also we can often use less memory for having one long path and not all in parallel.

3.It depends on your graph to use DFS or BFS.
This can optimize a choosen bottleneck and yield better average/minimal/maximal complexity.

Edit: duplicate at [Why DFS and not BFS for finding cycle in graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2869647/22810291)