# Cycles in family tree software

Tags: c++, graph, cycle, assertions, family-tree

I am the developer of some family tree software (written in C++ and Qt). I had no problems until one of my customers mailed me a bug report. The problem is that the customer has two children with their own daughter, and, as a result, he can't use my software because of errors.

Those errors are the result of my various assertions and invariants about the family graph being processed (for example, after walking a cycle, the program states that X can't be both father and grandfather of Y).

How can I resolve those errors without removing all data assertions?

Comment: [You should obviously write your software with Ray Stevens' song in mind.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlJH81dSiw)

Comment: If you trace your family tree backwards far enough, you will hit this problem far more often than you would like. Abandoning the tree representation may be painful but would ultimately be more correct.

Comment: You shouldn't add assertions for unlikely things, only impossible things.  Cycles are the obvious things that aren't possible in a family tree graph... no one can be his own ancestor via any method.  These other assertions are just bogus and should be removed.

Comment: @pgod instead of failing on these assertions, I think it's helpful to report unlikely things to the user to let them know they *may* have made a mistake but provide an easy and non-patronising method to proceed anyway.

Comment: This is not at all a silly question in the world of pet breeding. Daughter to father, mother to son, sister to brother, grandchildren to grandparents is standard technique there, and pet breeders need family tree software too. "Pure-bred" my ¤%#&.

Comment: This question is a great illustration about assumptions that software engineers make when producing code. Assertions have no place in production code for situations that *could* happen.

Comment: Are you guys *seriously* trying to close this as subjective and argumentative? The question is totally clear to me, it's asking for a solution to cycles in a tree / graph.

Comment: Do you get the same cycle error if cousins married, for instance a child of cousins that married would also be a child of the parent but also a cousin of the parent.  This is a common scenario.

Comment: Marrying first cousins was *very* common in Victorian England, especially among the upper classes (it was an excellent way to keep money within the family). Charles Darwin, for instance, married his first cousin, Emma Wedgwood. Any family tree software needs to support situations like this.

Comment: FYI, got linked here from [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/horu8/best_stack_overflow_question_ever/)

Comment: The thing is, it's not *technically* a tree any more, in the mathematical sense. As soon as you introduce (incestuous) cycles, it becomes a fully-fledged graph. So tell the customer to go buy a "family graph" program tailored for incestuous hicks. :-)

Comment: One of those rare cases where the crash report should go to the police not the developer.

Comment: @pgod: If a person marries the mother of a man who marries his mother, then he's his own grandpa.  Being your own ancestor _genetically_ is impossible, but socially it's not.  And most family tree software tracks both.

Comment: On 2013-02-07 I made a suggestion. Maybe it will yet be helpful to someone. If necessary, one may compromise with the difficult constraints of GEDCOM by entering a "person" that incorporates a group of people who have unsupported relationships. To illustrate the point, I called my example "Daddy-Daughter Inc." I openly admit that this is unpleasant toward people and fails to capture some facts in machine-readable form. Technically, does it not patch over a local problem in the GEDCOM representation of a family? Oh well. It was downvoted to -3 without comment, so I deleted it from the answers.

Comment: This is why it's good to challenge assertions strongly when gathering requirements. "X doesn't happen". Ok, but does that mean that "X doesn't *normally* happen", that "X will "*never*" happen", or that "X *cannot possibly* happen"?

Comment: No family tree (outside of time-travel fiction) has cycles, but the problem here is that your program doesn't support directed acyclic graphs, where one node can serve as more than one type of ancestor to another. Such graphs may be undesirable either morally, socially, or legally, but they are not biologically impossible.

Answer (score 726, accepted):

It seems you (and/or your company) have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a family tree is supposed to be.

Let me clarify, I also work for a company that has (as one of its products) a family tree in its portfolio, and we have been struggling with similar problems.

The problem, in our case, and I assume your case as well, comes from the [GEDCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEDCOM) format that is extremely opinionated about what a family should be. However this format contains some severe misconceptions about what a family tree really looks like.

GEDCOM has many issues, such as incompatibility with same sex relations, incest, etc... Which in real life happens more often than you'd imagine (especially when going back in time to the 1700-1800).

We have modeled our family tree to what happens in the real world: Events (for example, births, weddings, engagement, unions, deaths, adoptions, etc.). We do not put any restrictions on these, except for logically impossible ones (for example, one can't be one's own parent, relations need two individuals, etc...)

The lack of validations gives us a more "real world", simpler and more flexible solution.

As for this specific case, I would suggest removing the assertions as they do not hold universally.

For displaying issues (that will arise) I would suggest drawing the same node as many times as needed, hinting at the duplication by lighting up all the copies on selecting one of them.

Comment: This looks like the right approach, and it's easy enough to extend to detect more complex problems. You can work out a set of "A happened before B" relationships between events. For example, that a person was born before any other events involving them. This is a directed graph. You could then check that the graph contains no cycles. [See this question on StackOverflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph)

This should be ok until time travel is invented.

Comment: @paul-harrison If it where only that simple. In older records (even new ones) there are date inconsistencies. Baptism before birth, multiple birth records etc... So to an extent, in official records, there is time travel. We allow this inconsistent data. We allow users to indicate what the application should consider "the" birth record in case of duplicates. And we'll indicate broken timelines if found.

Comment: @ben-voigt GEDCOM is a format created by the The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints. The specification clearly states that marriage (MARR) is to be between men and women. For same sex marriage or incest the ASSO tag should be used (ASSOCIATES), also used to indicate friendship or being neighbours. It is clear the same sex marriage is second class relation within this spec. A more neutral spec would not demand male female relations.

Comment: @Bert Goethals: You are confusing GEDCOM with certain programs that do not support same-sex marriage (PAF, Legacy). GEDCOM does not preclude constructs such as "0 @F1@ FAM/1 HUSB @I1@/1 HUSB @I2@", and thus supports same-sex marriages if your software chooses to.

Comment: @Pierre You can cheat the system indeed. This is directly from the 5.5.1 docs: "MARR {MARRIAGE}: = A legal, common-law, or customary event of creating a family unit of a man and a woman as husband and wife." (http://homepages.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~pmcbride/gedcom/55gcappa.htm)
As you can see, no same sex marriage here.

Comment: @Bert Goethals: Here is a test which you can easily perform yourself: [1] Create a same-sex marriage in a Family Tree Maker file; [2] export to GEDCOM; [3] Import the GEDCOM file into RootsMagic. The same-sex marriage is preserved (vg. both partners are still male). How did that happen? Don't confuse what the spec. recommends, versus what is actually possible.

Comment: @TylerH I did mean at least. Also any "relation" could be expressed as a multiple of pairs. Eg: a threesome can be expressed as 2 relations per individual.

Comment: @Pierre My post is about the Spec; not about what other applications try to achieve by breaking the spec. A spec "specifies" not recommends. The fact that implementers are breaking the spec indicates that the spec is indeed flawed.

Answer (score 563):

Relax your assertions.

Not by changing the rules, which are mostly likely very helpful to 99.9% of your customers in catching mistakes in entering their data.

Instead, change it from an error "can't add relationship" to a warning with an "add anyway".

Comment: When encountering a *very unlikely* situation, that is, one where a user would *usually* only do it by mistake, it is a good idea to show the user a warning.  That's good feedback.  But then let the user go ahead if they are *really* sure they want to.  So I think this is a good answer, even if it doesn't get into the nuts and bolts of how.

Comment: Good answer! I just wonder, how this kind of software will handle "I am my own grandpa" (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlJH81dSiw) situation?

Comment: This is not really an answer, because I think the problem comes from actually traversing the tree? However, it is a good suggestion.

Comment: @bdwakefield: The question was "How do I resolve these errors, without removing all data assertions?"  I believe I've answered that.

Comment: @Ben It depends on what the assertions are for. If they prevent infinite loops or fatal errors from happening, then you are effectively suggesting to remove the assertions. If they are just there to warn a user of a potential mistake, then your answer is a good one.

Comment: @rm999: The question is pretty clear that the assertions are enforced after traversing the data structure.

Comment: @Ben I think we are reading the question differently. I interpret "cycle" to mean a cycle in the graph (which would mean during traversal). This makes sense in the context of the question: OP assumes a tree structure, and a child having the same father and grandfather is a loop and hence not a tree. Many tree traversal algorithms would fail on a graph with loops, so if my reading of the question is correct bdwakefield has an entirely legitimate point.

Answer (score 224):

Here's the problem with family trees: they are not trees. They are directed acyclic graphs or DAGs. If I understand the principles of the biology of human reproduction correctly, there will not be any cycles.

As far as I know, even the Christians accept marriages (and thus children) between cousins, which will turn the family tree into a family DAG.

The moral of the story is: choose the right data structures.

Comment: It would need a further restriction of every node having 1 or 2 maximum nodes pointing to it for in vitro and sexual reproduction. Although to be more true to real life, you might allow multiple dashed lines for uncertain descendancy on the father side (it's always clear who the mother is, but only DNA testing can insure who the father is, and that's rarely done even today), or even for both is adoption is taken into account.

Comment: @manixrock - since this question is about rare cases, i would like to assert that is not always clear who the mother is.  adoptions, abandoned babies, surrogate moms, etc can all complicate matters.

Comment: It's not necessarily acyclic, is it? Man-marries-grandmother.

Comment: Man marrying his on grandmother will not make himself his own grandfather and adding a cycle. If they have children, it will be a non-cycling regular graph edge.

Comment: It's actually TWO ADGs. There is the parentage graph and the legal relationship graph. Usually the same, but divergent more than one might expect.

Comment: Generally speaking there -will- be cycles. Just not cycles of the "parent of" type of relationship. There can very well be cycles in relationships generally, such as "married to", especially when you consider that these relationships change over time.

Comment: Assuming perfect knowledge and biology, there won't be any cycles in biological ancestry, but in the real world genealogy is full of "perhaps"-links. manxrock above, for example, asserts that it's always clear who the mother is. Which is not true in the real world. Yes, today DNA-testing can answer that question, but how are you going to get your relative from 5 generations back DNA-tested ?

Answer (score 115):

I guess that you have some value that uniquely identifies a person on which you can base your checks.

This is a tricky one. Assuming you want to keep the structure a tree, I suggest this:

Assume this: `A` has kids with his own daughter.

`A` adds himself to the program as `A` and as `B`. Once in the role of father, let's call it boyfriend.

Add a `is_same_for_out()` function which tells the output generating part of your program that all links going to `B` internally should be going to `A` on presentation of data.

This will make some extra work for the user, but I guess IT would be relatively easy to implement and maintain.

Building from that, you could work on code synching `A` and `B` to avoid inconsistencies.

**This solution is surely not perfect, but is a first approach.**

Comment: Probably such "proxy" nodes are indeed suitable solution. However I have no idea how can those be put in user interface without offending user. I can tell you that writing software that deals with real people (especially your customers) is not easy.

Comment: It never ends - B's new son will be his own uncle. I would consider a full refund for the program!

Comment: @Will A: And then realizes he is also his own mother, and recruits his younger self into the time agency?

Comment: Duplication (and syncing) of data within one system is bad practice. It indicates that the solution is sub optimal and should be reconsidered. If creating extra (duplicate) nodes would be needed, indicate it as a proxy and delegate the data reads and writes to the original node.

Answer (score 84):

You should focus on **what really makes value for your software**. Is the time spent on making it work for ONE consumer worth the price of the license ? Likely not.

I advise you to apologize to this customer, tell him that his situation is out of scope for your software and issue him a refund.

Comment: Very true. But also weigh other potential problems with similar troubles others have brought up.

Comment: Of course. The reasoning is : if it's a rare edge case on a non-critical application, you are not require to fix or implement anything. If it's really hurting your users, there's value in working on it.

Comment: Probably everybody has some case of incest somewhere in his/her ancestry. So you'll hit that bump if one digs family history (too) deep.

Comment: Making genealogy tree of some weird situation (inbreed royalty, Fritzl etc) is valid use of software.

Comment: A family tree software that won't allow second cousins to marry is useless. Nearly all families has atleast one case of this. Which is why I think the original example is made up for effect.

Answer (score 79):

You should have set up the [Atreides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_Atreides) family (either modern, [*Dune*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_Atreides), or ancient, *Oedipus Rex*) as a testing case. You don't find bugs by using sanitized data as a test case.

Comment: Sadly, way too many people first think of 'ok' data instead of the edge cases that break their systems.

Answer (score 59):

This is one of the reasons why languages like "Go" do not have assertions. They are used to handle cases that you probably didn't think about, all too often. **You should only assert the impossible, not simply the unlikely**. Doing the latter is what gives assertions a bad reputation. Every time you type `assert(`, walk away for ten minutes and *really* think about it.

In your particularly disturbing case, it is both conceivable and appalling that such an assertion would be bogus under rare but possible circumstances. Hence, handle it in your app, if only to say "This software was not designed to handle the scenario that you presented".

Asserting that your great, great, great grandfather being your father as impossible is a reasonable thing to do.

If I was working for a testing company that was hired to test your software, of course I would have presented that scenario. Why? Every juvenile yet intelligent 'user' is going to do *the exact same thing* and relish in the resulting 'bug report'.

Comment: Agree with 'when to use assertions' argument; don't see how it relates to 'some languages have asserts, Go doesn't.'

Comment: @Tim Post If you know it's impossible, then why bother asserting it?

Comment: @Red Hue - sometimes compilers make the impossible ... possible. Some versions of gcc think -10 == 10 in the abs() implementation.

Comment: @Red Hue: The whole point of assertions is to document and test conditions that should always be true (or false).  It helps keep you (and others) from "fixing" things in such a way that those impossible cases arise, as then they'd explicitly (rather than subtly) break the app.  If there's a valid reason for an "impossible" case to appear, then you've asserted too much.

Comment: @cHao @Tim Post I'm just trying to understand why Go not having assertions is a good thing since most of you agree that assertion is important to have.

Comment: @Red Hue: I imagine that point of view is based on cases like the original question, where assertions are being a bit abused.  Asserting too much (or too little) is more common than many people will realize, because people rarely learn to use assertions properly.  It's also a dev-time thing, which often won't be tested in production anyway, so some would conclude that the best way to handle it is to get rid of assertions altogether.  I disagree, but have some sympathy for the reasoning behind it.

Comment: If a language has assertions or not built in will hardly much impact on if developers will use an assertion pattern, or not, in their code. Many I am sure even do it without knowing that it's called an assertion...

Comment: Having assertions (or assertion-like code) is irrelevant. Code in languages like Go can and will make assumptions about the structure of data; it just can't document and enforce those assumptions with assertions. Bottom line: the application has a bug.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with language features.

Answer (score 41):

I hate commenting on such a screwed up situation, but the easiest way to not rejigger all of your invariants is to create a phantom vertex in your graph that acts as a proxy back to the incestuous dad.

Answer (score 37):

So, I've done some work on family tree software. I think the problem you're trying to solve is that you need to be able to walk the tree without getting in infinite loops - in other words, the tree needs to be acyclical.

However, it looks like you're asserting that there is only one path between a person and one of their ancestors. That will guarantee that there are no cycles, but is too strict.  Biologically speaking, descendancy is a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG). The case you have is certainly a degenerate case, but that type of thing happens all the time on larger trees.

For example, if you look at the 2^n ancestors you have at generation n, if there was no overlap, then you'd have more ancestors in 1000 AD than there were people alive. So, there's got to be overlap.

However, you also do tend to get cycles that are invalid, just bad data. If you're traversing the tree, then cycles must be dealt with. You can do this in each individual algorithm, or on load. I did it on load.

Finding true cycles in a tree can be done in a few ways. The wrong way is to mark every ancestor from a given individual, and when traversing, if the person you're going to step to next is already marked, then cut the link. This will sever potentially accurate relationships. The correct way to do it is to start from each individual, and mark each ancestor with the path to that individual. If the new path contains the current path as a subpath, then it's a cycle, and should be broken. You can store paths as vector<bool> (MFMF, MFFFMF, etc.) which makes the comparison and storage very fast.

There are a few other ways to detect cycles, such as sending out two iterators and seeing if they ever collide with the subset test, but I ended up using the local storage method.

Also note that you don't need to actually sever the link, you can just change it from a normal link to a 'weak' link, which isn't followed by some of your algorithms.  You will also want to take care when choosing which link to mark as weak; sometimes you can figure out where the cycle should be broken by looking at birthdate information, but often you can't figure out anything because so much data is missing.

Comment: Careful about those assumptions; one male and one female parent isn't a given when people adapt, or lesibans who consider themselves as parents, in the near future they may even be able to really *be* biologically the parents, atleast of girls. For that matter, if we apply dolly to humans, even the assumption "a person has two distinct parents" is out.

Comment: @Agrajag, yes that's why I specified "biologically speaking" for the cycle detection.  Even biologically, there are lots of possible issues, like surrogate mothers and artificial insemination.  If you also allow adoptions and other non-biological methods for defining parents, then it's possible to have a valid true cycle in a tree - for example, maybe someone adopts their grandparent when they get old and are no longer able to take care of themselves.  Making assumptions about people's family life is always complicated. But when writing software you need to make some assumptions..

Answer (score 36):

Another mock serious answer for a silly question:

The real answer is, use an appropriate data structure. Human genealogy cannot fully be expressed using a pure tree with no cycles. You should use some sort of graph. Also, talk to an anthropologist before going any further with this, because there are plenty of other places similar errors could be made trying to model genealogy, even in the most simple case of "Western patriarchal monogamous marriage."

Even if we want to ignore locally taboo relationships as discussed here, there are plenty of perfectly legal and completely unexpected ways to introduce cycles into a family tree.

For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_marriage

Basically, cousin marriage is not only common and expected, it is the reason humans have gone from thousands of small family groups to a worldwide population of 6 billion. It can't work any other way.

There really are very few universals when it comes to genealogy, family and lineage. Almost any strict assumption about norms suggesting who an aunt can be, or who can marry who, or how children are legitimized for the purpose of inheritance, can be upset by some exception somewhere in the world or history.

Comment: Your comment made me think of polygamy. Genealogy software that only models sexual reproduction may require a name attached to the sperm and the egg but broader definitions of family structure do not.

Comment: Genealogy software will often allow more than one spouse in the model. How you display the model in the view varies widely, even within one program, depending on the "mode" that has been provided.

Answer (score 20):

Potential legal implications aside, it certainly seems that you need to treat a 'node' on a family tree as a predecessor-person rather than assuming that the node can be the-one-and-only person.

Have the tree node include a person as well as the successors - and then you can have another node deeper down the tree that includes the same person with different successors.

Answer (score 13):

A few answers have shown ways to keep the assertions/invariants, but this seems like a misuse of assertions/invariant. Assertions are to make sure something that should be true is true, and invariants are to make sure something that shouldn't change doesn't change.

What you're asserting here is that incestuous relationships don't exist. Clearly they *do* exist, so your assertion is invalid. You can work around this assertion, but the real bug is in the assertion itself. The assertion should be removed.

Answer (score 8):

Your family tree should use directed relations. This way you won't have a cycle.

Answer (score 5):

Genealogical data is cyclic and does not fit into an acyclic graph, so if you have assertions against cycles you should remove them.

The way to handle this in a view without creating a custom view is to treat the cyclic parent as a "ghost" parent. In other words, when a person is both a father and a grandfather to the same person, then the grandfather node is shown normally, but the father node is rendered as a "ghost" node that has a simple label like ("see grandfather") and points to the grandfather.

In order to do calculations you may need to improve your logic to handle cyclic graphs so that a node is not visited more than once if there is a cycle.

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing is to `avoid creating a problem`, so I believe that you should **use a direct relation** to avoid having a cycle.

As @markmywords said, **#include "fritzl.h".**

Finally I have to say `recheck your data structure`. Maybe something is going wrong over there (maybe a bidirectional linked list solves your problem).

Answer (score 4):

## Assertions don't survive reality

Usually assertions don't survive the contact with real world data. It's a part of the process of software engineering to decide, with which data you want to deal and which are out of scope.

## Cyclic family graphs

Regarding family "trees" (in fact it are full blown graphs, including cycles), there is a nice anecdote:

> I married a widow who had a grown daughter. My father, who often visited us, fell in love with my step-daughter and married her. As a result, my father became my son, and my daughter became my mother. Some time later, I gave my wife a son, who was the brother of my father, and my uncle. My father's wife (who is also my daughter and my mother) got a son. As a result, I got a brother and  a grandson in the same person. My wife is now my grandmother, because she is my mother's mother. So I am the husband of my wife, and at the same time the step-grandson of my wife. In other words, I'm my own grandpa.

Things get even more strange, when you take [surrogates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogacy) or "fuzzy fatherhood" into account.

## How to deal with that

### Define cycles as out-of-scope

You could decide that your software should not deal with such rare cases. If such a case occurs, the user should use a different product. This makes dealing with the more common cases much more robust, because you can keep more assertions and a simpler data model.

In this case, add some good import and export features to your software, so the user can easily migrate to a different product when necessary.

### Allow manual relations

You could allow the user to add manual relations. These relations are not "first-class citizens", i.e. the software takes them as-is, doesn't check them and  doesn't handle them in the main data model.

The user can then handle rare cases by hand. Your data model will still stay quite simple and your assertions will survive.

Be careful with manual relations. There is a temptation to make them completely configurable and hence create a fully configurable data model. This will not work: Your software will not scale, you will get strange bugs and finally the user interface will become unusable. This anti-pattern is called ["soft coding"](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Soft_Coding), and ["The daily WTF"](http://www.thedailywtf.com/) is full of examples for that.

### Make your data model more flexible, skip assertions, test invariants

The last resort would be making your data model more flexible. You would have to skip nearly all assertions and base your data model on a full blown graph. As the above example shows, it is easily possible to be your own grandfather, so you can even have cycles.

In this case, you should extensively test your software. You had to skip nearly all assertions, so there is a good chance for additional bugs.

Use a test data generator to check unusual test cases. There are quick check libraries for [Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Introduction_to_QuickCheck1), [Erlang](http://www.quviq.com/products/erlang-quickcheck/) or [C](http://www.quviq.com/products/quickcheck-for-c/). For Java / Scala there are [ScalaCheck](http://scalacheck.org/) and [Nyaya](https://github.com/japgolly/nyaya). One test idea would be to simulate a random population, let it interbreed at random, then let your software first import and then export the result. The expectation would be, that all connections in the output are also in the input and vice verse.

A case, where a property stays the same is called an invariant. In this case, the invariant is the set of "romantic relations" between the individuals in the simulated population. Try to find as much invariants as possible and test them with randomly generated data. Invariants can be functional, e.g.:

- an uncle stays an uncle, even when you add more "romantic relations"
- every child has a parent
- a population with two generations has at least one grand-parent

Or they can be technical:

- Your software will not crash on a graph up to 10 billion members (no matter how many interconnections)
- Your software scales with O(number-of-nodes) and O(number-of-edges^2)
- Your software can save and re-load every family graph up to 10 billion members

By running the simulated tests, you will find lots of strange corner cases. Fixing them will take a lot of time. Also you will lose a lot of optimizations, your software will run much slower. You have to decide, if it is worth it and if this is in the scope of your software.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing all assertions, you should still check for things like a person being his/her own parent or other impossible situations and present an error. Maybe issue a warning if it is unlikely so the user can still detect common input errors, but it will work if everything is correct.

I would store the data in a vector with a permanent integer for each person and store the parents and children in person objects where the said int is the index of the vector. This would be pretty fast to go between generations (but slow for things like name searches). The objects would be in order of when they were created.

Answer (score -3):

Duplicate the father (or use symlink/reference).

For example, if you are using hierarchical database:

```
$ #each person node has two nodes representing its parents.
$ mkdir Family
$ mkdir Family/Son
$ mkdir Family/Son/Daughter
$ mkdir Family/Son/Father
$ mkdir Family/Son/Daughter/Father
$ ln -s Family/Son/Daughter/Father Family/Son/Father
$ mkdir Family/Son/Daughter/Wife
$ tree Family
Family
└── Son
    ├── Daughter
    │   ├── Father
    │   └── Wife
    └── Father -> Family/Son/Daughter/Father

4 directories, 1 file
```

Comment: The `ln -s` command doesn't work that way; the resolution of the link `Family/Son/Father` will look for `Family/Son/Daughter/Father` from under `Family/Son`, where the link resides, not from `.` where you issued the `ln -s` command.

Comment: cloning is prohibited by the geneva conventions