# data structure for Family tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I want to know that which data structure suits best for storing the family tree for a person, there are spousal, child and parental relationships. Also i want to know that if one person is has blood relationship with other.

It would be good i some data structure from c++ STL can be found.

Just ideas are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it homework?

Even if it's called “Tree”, It's a bad structure : imagine two brother who marry two sisters.

A general graph structure would be the best (a tree being a specific form of a graph). The edge would carry the relationship. Then you can run a path finding algorithm (like good old dijkstra) only on edges which represent blood relationship.

And boost::graph is a very good library.

Answer (score 4):

A **graph** would be best suited for this, and I suggest you use [`Boost`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html).

Note that building a family tree can prove to be tricky, as illustrated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163683/cycles-in-family-tree-software).

Otherwise, `std` doesn't define a graph data structure. And since a graph is obviously best suited for your situation, I suggest you either implement your own version, or use `Boost`.

Comment: I was just gonna post that link... +1 :)