# Traversing all descendants of an object

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, graph-algorithm, traversal

I'm having problems with traversing all descendants of an object.

The `'unit'` in the code below is of type `Unit` in my program. It has a property `ChildUnits` which returns a `List<Unit>` of the children of the unit.

I can successfully perform operations on the children. Then I check if those children have children, and if they do I can perform operations on them as well.

However, I need to check **all descendants** in case there is more depth than just grandchildren. I had a go with while loops in addition to the code below but it got really messy so I left it out.

This is the code I have reverted back to:

```
foreach (var child in unit.ChildUnits)
{
    //do something here with the child (I know it sounds dodgy).

    bool hasMoreChildren = child.ChildUnits.Count != 0;

    if(hasMoreChildren)
    {
        foreach (var descendant in child.ChildUnits)
        {
            //do something here with the descendant.
        }
    }
}
```

I could just go another level deep as it's relatively rare for a unit to have more depth than that. But that's not a clean solution.

I think I might need to use a graph traversal algorithm and/or recursion perhaps, but I would like some advice on how to solve this problem most efficiently.

**Edit: Is it possible to do this without defining a new function/method?**

Comment: You can use recursion and do the same with each child you have.

Comment: yes it's possible to do this using stack with loops instead of recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: Is it possible to do this without defining a new function/method?

You could use an anonymous method...which is not exactly "not defining a new method", I know :)

However, there's another issue you should take care of: Circular references... [even if you dont think there will be any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163683/cycles-in-family-tree-software)

Here's an implementation, without defining any new method

```
Action<IEnumerable<Unit>> process = null;
var processed = new HashSet<Unit>();
process = list => {
   foreach(var u in list.Where (processed.Add))
    {
        // do something here with u
        //... and then process children
        process(u.ChildUnits);
    }
};

process(myList); // do the actual processing
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. That question you linked to made me laugh! But in all seriousness, I will look into circular references.

Comment: I think hashsets orders elements so it will not keep the same order which it's inserted ?

Comment: Is the use of anonymous methods more efficient than using stack like the two other answers propose?

Comment: Using an anonymous method or a stack won't make a noticeable difference and my gut feeling tells me a stack will be a bit faster because it doesn't have to push methods and arguments on the stack (the program stack I mean). This is a hinge though, I have no data to back it up. A recursion though, (either with a method or an anonymous method) could cause a StackOverflowException (if your call hierarchy gets too deep aka too many items).

Comment: @Kenneth Thank you Kenneth. If I'm almost sure that the depth will very rarely go deeper than max 4 - Should I be concerned with the possibility of a StackOverFlowException ?

Comment: @mohaned no, a hashset is not ordered

Comment: @D.Singh A stackoverflow may occur if your hierarchy is more thousands of levels deep

Comment: And anonymous method is exactly the same as other answers... you dont see it, but the compiler generates methods behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm like this:

```
def traverse(Unit i):
       for (Unit child : i.childList):
                  // Perform your logic for child
                  traverse(child)
```

This will perform the same function for each child for the first node , and when applying it for i.child[j] it will perform the same function for all i.child[j].child[k] so it will perform what you want for each node and all its childs.

instead you can use stack :

```
stack s; 
s.push(firstNode);
while(!stack.empty()):
    t = stack.pop()
    foreach(Unit child : t):
        s.push(child)
        // Perform logic for child
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```
void processChildren(List<Unit> children)
{
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        //do something here with the child (I know it sounds dodgy).
        processChildren(child.Children); // recursive call here
    }
}
```

If you don't want to define a new method, you could also roll your own stack:

```
var stack = new Stack<Unit>();
stack.push(firstUnit);
while( !stack.Any() ) {
    var item = stack.pop();
    //do something here with the item

    foreach(var child in item.Children)
    {
        stack.push(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack class doesn't have isEmpty() method. Used the count != 0 instead.

Comment: Thanks, I used `!stack.Any()`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this without recursion or an action/lambda, is to use a list with items to handle.

Like this.

```
var toDoList = new List<Unit> { unit };
while (toDoList.Any()) {
    // Get current child, and remove it from the to-do-list
    var currentChild = toDoList.First();
    toDoList.RemoveAt(0);

    // Do something with the current child.
    // ...

    // Now see, if the child has any children to handle
    if (currentChild.ChildUnits != null && currentChild.ChildUnits.Any()) {
        toDoList.AddRange(currentChild.ChildUnits);
    }
}
```