# Find all the children gameObjects from the parent gameObject and assign it to a var gameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I find all children gameObjects of a parent (sub included: parent-child-children..) and assign it to a gameObject?

The below script finds all the children gameObjects of their current parent but does not find the sub children gameObjects of the found children.

```
public GameObject parent;
private GameObject AssignedChild;

 foreach (Transform eachChild in parent.transform)
        {
            if (eachChild.gameObject.tag == "TagOfTheObject")
            {
               //assign the tagged GameObject to "AssignedChild" GameObject
               AssignedChild = eachChild.gameObject;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Might be a good time for a recursive method. Check this post out (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304000/traversing-all-descendants-of-an-object)

Comment: Also, a `GameObject` field holds a *single* object, if you want to store *all* of them, you will need an array or list.

Comment: @Draco18s no i only want to find single gameObject since I am assigning unique tags to each object and then assign each to each gameObject.

Comment: *`assign them to gameObject`* "them" is a plural noun. But if each object has a unique tag, [`GameObject.FindWithTag()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)?

Comment: Sorry I corrected it, assigning is not an issue. Finding sub and sub children gameObjects is the issue. My hierarchy is "Parent - child - children - subchildren- etc"

Comment: Just checking, Is there some reason to not just make AssignedChild public and then drag the thing you want to look up there in the editor?

Comment: I can but I was looking for different approach since I will be attaching this script to multiple gameObjects :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add one line to find all the children gameObjects

```
public GameObject parent;
private GameObject AssignedChild;

 foreach (Transform eachChild in parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
        {
            if (eachChild.gameObject.tag == "TagOfTheObject")
            {
               //assign the tagged GameObject to "AssignedChild" GameObject
               AssignedChild = eachChild.gameObject;
            }

        }
```