# Simple implementation for detecting cycles in a directed graph in C#

Tags: c#, graph, implementation, cycle

I wonder if you could help me with a *simple* implementation for detecting cycles in a directed graph in C#.

I've read about the [algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph) but I'd like to find something already implemented, very simple and short.

I don't care about the performance because the data size is limited.

Comment: Whoever voted to close should post a comment why.  This seems a perfectly valid question

Answer (score 3):

Check out [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) - it has loads of the algorithms implemented and it's quite a nice library to use.

Comment: It seams your codeplex link is gone, but a fork is on github https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/QuickGraph

Answer (score 3):

Run a DFS on G and check for backedges.

At every node you expand just check if it is already in the currrent path.