# How linkedin or google query information about connection in circles

Tags: database, performance, algorithm, graph-databases

Ok, now on linkedin or in google we could see circles. For example circle 1 - my friends. circle 2 - friends of my friends, circle 3 - friends of friends of my friends and so on. I'm qurious - how they query that info. Which technology allow to do it easy and fast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find connections between users so I can create a closed friend circle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034764/how-to-find-connections-between-users-so-i-can-create-a-closed-friend-circle)

Comment: No, that's not duplicate. In question you provide person ask about different things from my. he ask how to do that, but I asking about how person in google or linkedin do that and what technologies they use. That's not the same.

Comment: @Ph0en1x do you really think they would tell you how it works? For LinkedIn they have published the technology on their tech blog. So better do the research before asking a question.

Comment: Here's the link btw: http://engineering.linkedin.com/real-time-distributed-graph/using-set-cover-algorithm-optimize-query-latency-large-scale-distributed