# How to find which vertices are in a graph cycle

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

eg. for 1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 4->2, I want to print 2, 3, 4.
I tried DFS, and when I found vertex I visited before, I go to parent until I don't get this vertex, but it does not work well. Sometimes it enters an infinite loop.

Run dfs:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_VER; i += 1)
    if (ver[i].v == 0 && ver[i].nb > 0)
        dfs(i);
```

dfs:

```
ver[v].v = 1;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < ver[v].nb; i += 1) {
    ver[ver[v].to[i]].p = v;

    if (ver[ver[v].to[i]].v == 0)
        dfs(ver[v].to[i]);
    else
        // cycle found
        printCycle(ver[v].to[i]);
}
```

and print cycle:

```
printf("\cycle: %d ", v);

int p = ver[v].p;

while (p != v) {
    printf("%d(%d) ", p, v);

    p = ver[p].p;
}

printf("\n");
```

Vertex struct:

```
int *to; // neighbor list

int nb; // how many neighbor
int p; // parent
short v; // was visited? 0 = false, 1 = true
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best algorithm for detecting cycles in a directed graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for "Strongly Connected Components" - so you are in luck, there is a well known algorithm for finding these in a graph. See [Tarjan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm).

The algorithm is pretty well described in that article, but it's a bit long winded so I won't paste it here. Also, unless you are doing this for study you will probably be better off using an existing implementation, it's not *that* hard to implement but it's not *that* easy either.

**EDIT**. It looks like this question is actually a dupe... it pains me to say this but it probably needs to be closed, sorry. See [Best algorithm for detecting cycles in a directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph)

Answer (score 0):

You should use vertex coloring to avoid infinite loop in DFS.
At first all vertices are marked as WHITE. When you discover a vertex at first time (it is marked as WHITE) you should mark it is as GREY. If you discovered a GREY vertex you would find a loop.

Comment: And how does this tell you which vertices are in the loop?

Comment: You can use std::map or std::unordered_map to hold vertex type.