# Find a circuit in a direct graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I want to find a circuit in a direct graph , this circuit starts at a specific vertex and ends at it. I use adjacency list data structure to create this graph but I could n't know how the algorithm would be, please help me.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try [Googling it](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=detect+cycles+in+directed+graph&oq=detect+cycles+in+dir&aq=0&aqi=g1g-q2&aql=&gs_l=hp.3.0.0j0i22l2.5304.10257.0.11144.20.12.0.8.8.0.208.1915.0j11j1.12.0...0.0.-eh4kSQJRfQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d0f8cd49a0fc8cd2&biw=1138&bih=555)?

Comment: You can use Tarjan's algorithm. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph

Comment: Thanks for all , I get the point and I'll try and post my atemption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this hint will help:

1. traverse graph (any algo - BFS DFS)
2. Color node which you've visited 
   AND Store its parent
3. check if the node you're traversing is
   already colored, then loop back to its parents until you get same
   node.

Answer (score 0):

DFS would find a cycle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: Thanks for all. I get the point and I'll try and post my attempt soon

Answer (score 0):

```
void DFS (Node* ptr , int node , int index , int n )
```

{
    int i;

```
if ( ptr == NULL)
{
    ptr=arrNode[index].next;
    node = ptr->vertex;
}

for ( int i=0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
    if ( ( node == arrNode[i].vertex) && (ptr->visit=false))
    {
        ptr=arrNode[i].next;
        ptr->visit = true;
        s.push(arrNode[i].vertex);
    }
    ptr=ptr->next;
    DFS(ptr,ptr->vertex,i+1 , n );

}
```

}

Comment: I have written this code , there is something wrong I can't get it.
My data structure is an array its length = vertex number , each field of this array has a pointer to linked list which contains all its neighbors :(

Comment: This would probably be better edited into your question, so that readers can see your current work. I am sure once you do so, you will get more positive responses - best of luck `:)`