# Finding out folder cyclic references

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, logic

Suppose I have an app that transfers files placed inside a main folder to some other location.

For example, user can configure the app as below:

```
If placed in C:\X\A Transfer to C:\Z\A
If placed in C:\Y\B Transfer to C:\Z\B
. . .
. . .
```

Till now, all is well. But the following configuration would create endless transfer loops:

```
if placed in C:\X\A Transfer to C:\Z\A
if placed in C:\Z\A Transfer to C:\Z\B
if placed in C:\Z\B Transfer to C:\X\A
```

Such hierarchies can get quite complex. What would be the best way to predict them and prevent such configurations in the first place?

Comment: Simple and obvious solution is to only follow the rules from top-down per file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically looking for cycles in a directed graph. I would use a graph Library like QuickGraph: http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Strongly%20Connected%20Components&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Agreed.  See also this SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph

Answer (score 4):

Assume that there is a class like this:

```
class Rule
{
    public string sourceDir; // dir file placed
    public string targetDir; // dir to move to
}
```

And a dictionary that contains all your rules indexed by the `sourceDir` named `rules`.

You can write a function like this:

```
public bool RuleCausesCycle(Rule rule)
{
    return RuleCausesCycle(rule, new HashSet(CaseInsensitiveComparer.Default));
}

private bool RuleCausesCycle(Rule rule, Set visited)
{
     Rule targetRule;

     if (visited.Contains(rule.sourceDir))
     {
         return true;
     }

     if (rules.TryGetValue(rule.targetDir, out targetRule))
     {
         visited.Add(rule.sourceDir);

         return RuleCausesCycle(targetRule, visited);
     }

     return false;
}
```

Comment: If the assumption that there is only one target dir per one source dir (you dont make two copies from the same source directory) holds, this is a better solution than the other answer. If it does not hold, you can add a loop (and not use a dictionary), but it can get very resource-expensive very fast.

Comment: A dictionary with a list would be required if you had multiple rules with the same source. It wouldn't get resource intensive nor slow unless you had millions of rules