# How to determine if locking order is in conflict

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, locking

If I have empirical data on what locks were acquired in what orders by which thread and line of code, how can I then use that data to determine if locking order has deadlock potential?

l = lock
u = unlock

e.g.: these are in conflict and might deadlock

```
thread 1: l1, l2, u2, u1
thread 2: l2, l1, u1, u2
```

Or even this single thread is in conflict with itself since I don't really know that the second half of the sequence wouldn't be run on a separate thread in a different use case.

```
thread 1: l1, l2, u2, u1, l2, l1, u1, u2
```

Is there a suitable algorithm that can be used to determine that from the data?

Note I am asking not what to find (different lock aquisition orders), but what algorithm or data structure to use to find them given a set of empirical data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a lock ordering graph, and check for cycles.

Whenever a lock is acquired while another is held, add an edge from the held lock to the acquired lock.

Your example:

```
thread A: lock 1, lock 2, unlock 2, unlock 1
thread B: lock 2, lock 1, unlock 1, unlock 2
```

Because thread A locks 2 while holding 1, and thread B locks 1 while holding 2, you have these edges:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 1
```

[Making this graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=directed+1-%3E2%2C+2-%3E1):

[image: Graph rendering]

Which has cycles, so there are potential deadlocks.

See: [directed cycle detection algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph)

**Caveat**

*Technically*, cycles that are made entirely out of edges that all come from one thread can't cause deadlocks (since you're probably using [re-entrant locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex)). So those cycles aren't really deadlocks... they're time bombs. Some apparently innocent change to threading in the future will set them off, turning them into a deadlock, and ruin your day.

You *can* refine this algorithm to avoid that case, but I'm not going to bother because what you'd be ignoring is also bad.

Comment: Yes, u=unlock, l=lock. I'll amend the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have just run into the classic **lock-ordering deadlock** problem.

> A program will be free of lock-ordering deadlocks if all threads
>   acquire the locks they need in a fixed global order. (*from [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)*)

If you detect in your data that different threads acquired the same locks in different order, then your program can potentially suffer a lock-ordering deadlock with unlucky timing. So that's the pattern to look for in your data; it's that simple.

---

**UPDATE**: Here is an algorithm how I would do it. I don't know whether it has a name.

For each lock event `li` from the left to right:

- find its corresponding unlock event (or use the end of the sequence if it is never released)
- add all enclosed lock events as pairs `(i,j)` where `j` is an enclosed lock event
- then go to the next lock event and repeat.

An example follows.

[image]

For example, for the first event `lA` it means scanning through the sequence to find the first occurrence of `uA`. This gives us the subsequence: `lA lB uA`. For each lock event in this subsequence add a pair into a set. In this case, save `(A,B)` in the set. (If we had another lock event in this subsequence, say
`lA lB lD uA`, we would add the pair `(A,D)` as well to the set.)

Now let's prepare the next subsequence. For the next lock event in the orgininal sequence, that is `lB`, find the first `uB` following it. This gives the subsequence is `lB uA lC uB` and the only pair that needs to be saved in the set is `(B,C)`.

For the third subsequence, for the `lC` event there is no pair to be saved as there is no lock event in the `lC uB` subsequence.

The set of `thread 1` contains the pairs `(A,B)` and `(B,C)`. I would simple create another set containing the reversed pairs `(B,A)` and `(C,B)`; let's call it the forbidden set.

I would repeat this procedure for `thread 2`, prepare the container with the pairs telling which locks were acquired in what order by `thread 2`. Now, if the set intersection of this set and the forbidden set of `thread 1` is not empty, then we have detected a potential lock-ordering deadlock.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I haven't run into it, I want to know if I have the potential to run into it. My question was how to look for the ordering with an algorithm. I can see it with my eyes, but am unsure how to process the data.

Comment: @idij It is not quite clear what you are asking. Do you want me to write some pseudo-code to find patterns where locks were acquired in different global order?

Comment: Well, the name of a suitable algorithm I can read up on would also be suitable. Apologies if the question was unclear, but I do not want to ask what pattern to look for (different ordering of lock acquisition), but *how* to look for it.

Comment: @idij You could probably solve it with an [order-maintaince](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-maintenance_problem) data structure as well. However, I think what I write in my answer is simple and efficient enough. It is also easy to figure out where exactly can deadlocks happen. With an order-maintenance data structure, it would not be that easy.

Comment: @idij You can also regard my answer as a recipe to get the directed edges in Strilac's answer. (Well, sort of.)

Comment: I've picked Strilac's answer (updated following your feedback) because I can see more clearly how I can apply it, though I will use elements from your answer also. I have learned a lot from your answer and comments and wanted to acknowledge that. Very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @idij Okay. Yes, the true answer is somewhere in between, the mix of the two as his answer doesn't tell you how to find the edges. In any case, I am glad my answer was helpful.