# Detect Cyclic Dependancy in Hashmap in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, cyclic-dependency

I have a hashmap of:

```
Tables => Set of Parent Tables [ HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> ]
```

Example of non-cyclic case could be:

```
A -> [B,C]
D -> [B,C]
B -> [C]
c -> []
```

Example of cyclic case would be:

```
A -> [B,C]
B -> [C]
C -> [A]
```

I want to reject the cyclic cases and hence need a function which could detect if the provided hashmap has any cycles or not :

```
public boolean hasDependencies(HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> objectAndItsDependentsMap)
{
   //Implementation
}
```

I have read posts suggesting algorithms to detect cycles but being a newbie to java could not use that knowledge to makeup the above function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a rough implementation based solely on your example. I suggest testing against other examples.

```
public boolean hasDependencies(Map<String, Set<String>> objectAndItsDependentsMap) {
    for (String node : objectAndItsDependentsMap.keySet()) {
        final Set<String> directNeighbors = objectAndItsDependentsMap.get(node);
        for (String directNeighbor : directNeighbors) {
            Set<String> next = objectAndItsDependentsMap.get(directNeighbor);
            while (next != null) {
                for (String n : next) {
                    next = objectAndItsDependentsMap.get(n);
                    if (next != null && (next.contains(n) || next.contains(node))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I think this code will fail if I make a slight change to my example as:

a -> b, b -> c, c -> d, d -> a

Comment: @lostcoderx I've edited my answer. Please check if it suits you now.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you read about and implement Tarjan's algorithm.

[Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%E2%80%99s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm)

I used it some time ago. It's quite efficient.

See also:

[Best algorithm for detecting cycles in a directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph)

Comment: I read it but as I mentioned, I am unable to translate in java according to my use case :(