# Can I use just a simple Set for cycle detection in directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have seen quite a lot of algorithms to do *cycle detection*, such as [Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) answered in [Best algorithm for detecting cycles in a directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph).

I never thought detecting a cycle would be that complicated and I always believed a simple `Set` can help solve the problem.

So in addition to the usual `marker` array for recording visited vertices, we can use an additional `Set` to record all vertices along a path from the source.

The key thing is to remember to remove a vertex from the set after all its next neighbours are done.

A trivial code is like this:

```java
public boolean hasCycle(List<Integer>[] vs) {
  boolean[] marker = new boolean[v.length];
  Set<Integer> tracker = new HashSet<Integer>();

  for(int v = 0;v < vs.length;v++)
    if (explore(v, vs, marker, tracker)) return true;

  return false;
}

private boolean explore(int v, List<Integer>[] vs, boolean[] marker, Set<Integer> tracker) {
  if (tracker.contains(v)) return true;
  else if (!marker[v]) {
    marker[v] = true;
    tracker.add(v); // add current vertex to tracker
    for (int u:vs[v]) if (explore(v, vs, marker, tracker)) return true;
    tracker.remove(v); // remove the vertex from tracker, as it is fully done.
  }
  else return false;
}
```

Is there any problem about this algorithm?

---

With help from sasha's answer, actually even the set is not necessary and just an array is enough.

```java
public boolean hasCycle(List<Integer>[] vs) {
  boolean[] marker = new boolean[v.length];
  boolean[] onPath = new boolean[v.length];

  for(int v = 0;v < vs.length;v++)
    if (explore(v, vs, marker, onPath)) return true;

  return false;
}

private boolean explore(int v, List<Integer>[] vs, boolean[] marker, boolean[] onPath) {
  if (onPath[v]) return true;
  else if (!marker[v]) {
    marker[v] = true;
    onPath[v] = true; // add current vertex to the path
    for (int u:vs[v]) if (explore(v, vs, marker, onPath)) return true;
    onPath[v] = false; // remove the vertex from the path, as it is fully done.
  }
  else return false;
}
```

Comment: You're right, simple DFS is enough to detect cycles in a graph, in precisely the way you do it: Check for back-edges. Tarjan's algorithm actually computes something more complicated

Comment: @NiklasB. but is this code or using set correct?

Comment: Each cycle induces a back-edge in the depth-first tree, which is what you're checking for. Looks good to me, but of course there might be subtle implementation bugs that I overlooked.

Comment: Instead of using two arrays, some people prefer to use an array of bytes and use 3 different values to encode the states not visited/on the root path/visited. That would be even more space efficient.

Comment: @NiklasB. seems like a nice idea thanks :)

Comment: @NiklasB. but two boolean arrays are worse?

Comment: @JacksonTale Well that depends. `boolean` takes 1 byte, so it's kind of a waste because 1 byte can actually store 256 different values, not just 2. Of course if you would use a proper bitvector, 2 bits per node is close to optimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in java but talking about C++ passing set etc in recursion is not time efficient. Also set takes **O(log(n))** in inserting/deleting an element. Your logic looks correct to me. But you can do it more efficiently and easily by keeping two arrays **parent[]** and **visited[]**. Basically do a bfs and following is the pseudo code ( **visited** is initialized to all zeros ) .

```
   /* There are n nodes from 0 to n-1 */
   visited[0]=1
   parent[0]=0
   flag=0
   queue.push(0)
   while the queue is not empty
       top = queue.front()
       queue.pop()
       for all neighbors x of top
           if not visited[top]
              visited[x]=1
              parent[x]=top
              queue.push(x)
           else if visited[x] is 1 and parent[top] is not x
                flag = 1

   if flag is 1 cycle is there otherwise not
```

As it may not be necessary that starting from 0 all nodes are visited . So repeat until all nodes are visited. Complexity is **O(E+V)** slightly better than the complexity of your method **O(E+VlogV)**. But it is simple to write and  not recursive.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. HashSet in Java is O(1) op as it doesn't use a tree. However you are right that set not necessary as a simple array is enough

Comment: The advantage of using DFS over BFS is that the call stack will contain the nodes of the cycle, which is not the case for BFS.