# Identify Loops Within Dependency Map

Tags: ruby, algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory

I'm working on a gem called ActiveTouch.  It's for creating complex touch or cache invalidation networks.  Currently, I'm trying to determine a way of identifying loops within the network.

A simplified version of a dependency map is a hash where the key represents a Model, and the value represents models that are touched.

For example

```
{ 
  A => [B, C],
  B => [D, F],
  D => [A]
}
```

In this example we can see there is a dependency loop between A and D, A->B->D->A or D->A->B->D

In order to determine a loop, I need to see all possible paths.  How can I see all possible paths, like this:

```
[
  [A, B, D, A],
  [A, B, F],
  [A, C],
  ...
  [D, A, B, D]
]
```

A response in Ruby would be great, but any language will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your question boils down to finding a loop in a graph.

You already have your graph stored here, as an [adjacency list representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). Detecting cycles is a [standard procedure](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/) and can be done with a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm. You start with some vertex and run DFS till you will see some vertex twice.

If you have disconnected graph, you do this on all the components.

Comment: Thanks!  Been a while since I have gotten to do fun programming like this and can't remember it from school!  I looked a little further and found a ruby example of Tarjan's in another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph