# How to detect circular reference in a Tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, guava, tree-traversal

I have a Node class as follows:

```
public class Node{
    Object data;
    List<Node> children;
}
```

I need to traverse this tree in post order and I am using [Guava TreeTraverser](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser.html) for for the same.

```
    TreeTraverser<Node> treeTraverser = new TreeTraverser<Node>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<Node> children(Node node) {
                    return node.children;
                }
            };

treeTraverser.postOrderTraversal(node);
```

The catch is that there chances that the given tree could have circular dependencies(means it could be a cyclic graph). What would be an efficient way to detect circular dependencies?

Comment: A cycle occurs when you visit a node you've visited before. So keep track of the nodes you've already visited (e.g. in a `Set`) and error if you've already seen that node.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By definition, a tree is an [*acyclic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic) connected graph. Therefore, there is no such thing as a tree with circular dependencies.

You can find cycles in a graph by applying depth-first traversal, and looking for nodes that have been visited the way down. If you visit a node that you have seen during prior steps of DFS, the graph is *not* a tree.

See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/261573/335858) for advanced cycle detection algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

In simple words `Tree is a non cyclic data structure` and when there are cycles then it becomes a `Graph`.

[image]

Above is an example of a graph. You can represent it using Adjacency list or adjacency matrix. You can refer to http://krishnalearnings.blogspot.in/2015/11/basics-of-graph-in-computer-science.html for basics of Graphs.

In the picture above we can represent it as below (In your question, you have used an adjacency list kind of representation).

```
int[][] graph = {   {0,1,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,1,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,1},
                    {0,1,0,0,0,0},
                };
```

1 represents an edge from corresponding row numbered vertex to column numbered vertex.

We can write a simple method to detect the presence of cycle and also print any one cycle in the graph.

```
static int[] cycleElements;
static int cycleElementIndex = 0;
static boolean cycleFound = false;
static final int NEW = 0;
static final int PUSHED = 1;
static final int POPPED = 2;
public static int findCycle(int[][] graph,int N, int u, int[] states){
    for(int v = 0; v < N; v++){
        if(graph[u][v] == 1){
            if(states[v] == PUSHED){
                // cycle found
                cycleFound = true;
                return v;
            }else if(states[v] == NEW){
                states[v] = PUSHED;
                int poppedVertex = findCycle(graph, N, v, states);
                states[v] = POPPED;
                if(cycleFound){
                    if(poppedVertex == u){
                        cycleElements[cycleElementIndex++] = v;
                        cycleElements[cycleElementIndex++] = u;
                        cycleFound = false;
                    }else{
                        cycleElements[cycleElementIndex++] = v;
                        return poppedVertex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 6;
    int[][] graph = {   {0,1,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,1,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,1,1,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,1},
                        {0,1,0,0,0,0},
                    };
    cycleElements = new int[N];
    int[] states = new int[N];
    states[0] = PUSHED;
    findCycle(graph,N,0,states);
    for(int i = 0; i < cycleElementIndex; i++){
        System.out.println(cycleElements[i]);
    }
}
```

You can easily transform above approach to adjacency list if you wish, though representation does not matter much ( only adjacency list may save your space as compared to adjacency matrix)