# Find all cycles in directed graph

Tags: python, graph, path, cycle

I'm using the following python code to find out any cycle in graph but it doesn't return correct results

```
for node in graph:
    new_path=node
    path = node
    for adjacent in graph.get(node, []):
        if not adjacent in new_path:
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(adjacent)
        else:
            print (new_path)
```

Could you please help me find any cycles in the graph?

Input Sample:

```
graph = {
    '181': set(['284','248','247','350']),
    '350': set(['400', '401']),
    '400': set(['181', '654'])
}
```

Desired Output:

```
181 350 400 181
```

My code does not currently output anything.

Comment: What inputs, what are you expecting to get out, what are you actually getting out?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Input: graph in standard structure of python. Out put, list of cycles paths.

Comment: I meant an actual sample input, output and explanation of how it differs from the expected.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've attached samples

Comment: And what are you expecting to see?

Comment: Alternatively, what are you seeing instead of the sample output? It is not clear of the sample output is what you want or what you are actually getting.

Comment: @MadPhysicist nothing in results. I said the sample output

Comment: Your output looks fine. What is the actual problem?

Comment: BTW, you can define a `set` with just `{'284','248','247','350'}`. No need for the `set([])` part.

Comment: It doesn't returns value

Comment: That's because you aren't returning a value anywhere? Please provide more context. Is this in a function somewhere?

Comment: @MadPhysicist no just a simulation which includes just this function

Comment: And it's producing the expected output. So what do you mean that it doesn't return a value?

Comment: In this time it doesn't return any result. Nothing!

Comment: I think I understand now. Sorry about the miscommunication. Close vote removed.

Comment: One more request. Could you please explain what you think your code is doing?

Comment: @MadPhysicist well I think it starts from a node and for each adjacent to the node, checks whether the adjacent is located on path or not. Then detects the cycles.

Comment: You reset the path on every iteration of the outer loop. This looks like a problem better solved by recursion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist suggests that I point out that this problem has been answered elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph.