# Find the number of cycles in a graph (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I have to find the number of cycles in a graph.

I have a set of nodes connected to each other which have the following structure:

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self, id, value):
     self.divergencePoint = 0
     self.convergencePoint = 0
     self.id = id
     self.value = value
     self.parents = []
     self.children = []
```

I have successfully created the graph and the fields divergencePoint and
convergencePoint are set to 1 if it is a convergence point or a divergence point.

Now how can I detect the cycles ?

Comment: Can you be more precise. How do you define a diamond?

Comment: I see more diamonds. What is your definition of a diamond?

Comment: So in this case, divergence points are A and D, and convergence points are D and E?

Comment: A diamond is a subgraph delimited by a divergence point followed by a convergence point where one or several nodes are present between these two points with the condition that all the "flows" traverse both points

Comment: @Rawing yes it is

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph

Comment: @LukeSky Can you label other vertices too? From what I've understood, I think there is another convergence point connected to D.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already found the convergence and divergence points, this is an easy task. You start at a divergence point and recursively add its children to the diamond until you encounter a convergence point.

```
for node in divergence_nodes:
    diamond= {node}
    queue= node.children[:]

    while queue:
        node= queue.pop()
        if node in diamond:
            continue

        diamond.add(node)

        if not node.convergencePoint:
            queue+= node.children
```