# Cyclic dependencies in dict

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, dependencies, cyclic-dependency

I'm working on small tool to manage dependencies between applications. For example app_one depends on app_two and app_three. Simplest way to store those relations is dict

```
dep = {
'app_one': 'app_two',
'app_two': '',
'app_three': 'app_one, app_four',
'app_four': 'app_two, app_three'
}
```

Now I'm wonder how to find such cyclic dependencies like between app_three and app_four..  Or maybe I should use something different than dict.

Iterating through dict and manually fining that relations could be slow and not efficient.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to build a graph and use [known algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph) to find cycles.

Comment: Thank's looks like it solved my problem.